# References in captions out of order

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a document that starts with a LOC and LOF with references in the main body text and one reference in a figure caption. For some reason the reference in the figure caption is numbered 1 and listed first in the bibliography even though it should be 4.

I've loaded the notoccite package in the preamble and and the caption is written like:

```
\caption[Horiba LabRam PL Set up]{Horiba LabRam Photoluminescence Set up. Adapted from ~\cite{Horiba2014}}
```

But neither of those fixes seems to work. The bibliography style I'm using is unsrt.

Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: have you re-run bibtex since adding the `[]` argument to keep the `\cite` out of the list of figures?

Comment: Ah yes thanks that's worked! I was compiling with Pdflatex+makeindex+bibtex so thought it would work but obviously you need to do bibtex on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After correcting the `\caption`  to use the optional argument to avoid using `\cite` in the table of contents, you need to re-run latex to generate a corrected `aux` file, then bibtex to regenerate the reordered bibliography, then latex again to typeset the corrected bibliography.